# Why is my CSS file not working in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

I've read a bunch of other people's solution to this but can't seem to get anything to work. My CSS file in Django is not connecting to my HTML. The site runs just fine, and no errors are given, but my formatting in the CSS isn't loading.

Here is my structure:
[image]
This is my CSS file:

```css
.pagination {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.pagination-number {
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6D85C7;
}

.pagination-number:hover, .pagination-current {
    background-color: #3354AA;
}

.pagination-action {
    margin: 0 0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    color: #B9B9B9;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.pagination-action:hover, .pagination-previous, .pagination-next {
    color: #3354AA;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #96f226;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
}
```

I load the CSS file in my HTML file (policy_list.html) with:

```html
{% load static %}
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" type="text/css" />

...

 <div class="pagination">

              {% if policies.has_previous %}
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page=1">
                 <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              {% endif %}

              {% for num in policies.paginator.page_range %}

                {% if policies.number == num %}
                <span class="pagination-number pagination-current">{{ num }}</span>
                {% elif num > policies.number|add:'-3' and num < policies.number|add:'3' %}
                <a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}

              {% endfor %}

              {% if policies.has_next %}
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ policies.next_page_number }}">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ policies.paginator.num_pages }}">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              {% endif %}

            </div>
```

But this CSS file is not being loaded when I run my Django site. For reference, here is my settings.py file:

```html
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
 )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I can't figure out why the CSS will not work with the HTML. I've tried messing around with the urls.py file as well but to no avail. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are referencing `styles.min.css` while the screenshot is showing a `blog.css`?

Answer (score 0):

Is django.contrib.staticfiles in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and is DEBUG set to True?

Check [Django Doc's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) for an explanation on why static files are not working when DEBUG is set to False in settings.py

Comment: whoops, I meant to change that in code snippet posted. I had it as blog.css like you suggested, though it still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Check your console, does it make a GET request for your CSS file? Like "GET /static/blog.css/" whenever you load your page?

Comment: Is django.contrib.staticfiles in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and is DEBUG set to False?

Comment: Cool, check Django's docs for an explanation why static files are not working when Debug is set to True in dev environment. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). I'll edit my answer above, please don't forget to accept. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your folder's naming convention might also cause that, '*css*/blog.css'.. The css should be the name of the application instead. Like so {% static 'app_name/blog.css' %}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).